# Are there any OVA of Sword Art Online series?

Tags: sword-art-online

Are there any OVAs of *Sword Art Online* series which have been released and if they affect the main story or not?

Answer (score 2):

There's only Extra Edition, an Special set after the events of Fairy Dance. The first half is a recap of the first season disguised as an interview. The second half is anime original material, it doesn't affect the main story-line, but it follows ALOs in-game back-story set in Norse Mythology, name-dropping the Aesir. This setting has only been touched upon in the anime and in the LN release during the Caliber arc of the Second Season, but there's a bunch of other short stories that further this setting that have been self-published by Kawahara Reki as his former pen-name Kunori Fumio.